# Scrapy - how to give up a response (yield nothing) from spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

In my spider `parse` looks like:

```
if isValid1:
    foo()
    if isValid2:
        bar()
            if isValid3:
                yield baz
```

I wonder if I can organize the code like the following by giving up this response:

```
if not isValid1:
    giveUp()
foo()
if not isValid2:
    giveUp()
bar()
if not isValid3:
    giveUp()
yield baz
```

Comment: Can't you just return ?

Comment: That did the trick....how silly my question was... I though a normal `return` or `yield` would pass a `None` to the `pipelines` module, but it actually doesn't.